# Sharepoint Search doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2007

Platform: MOSS 2007 on server 2008

Sharepoint is working etc...

Problem: When you search for something, it doesn't find anything, no errors.

Authentication and permissions look fine. Search service is up and running.

What could be the problem? Any checkpoints I might have missed, any bad configurations I should check, etc...?

Answer (score 6):

- You should start with checking the crawl log files. That will probably give some valuable information.
- Also double check that the SSP is set up correctly, with a valid content source setup, valid starting addresses, [schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092597/sharepoint-search-doesnt-work/1092635#1092635) etc.
- Make sure that no crawl rules prohibit any searches.
- And lastly, no 3rd party/custom security trimmers installed that prohibit results to be shown.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't work is not a lot of use is it.

My first guess is: Have you configured the search correctly (crawl schedules, content sources etc.)

To setup search (crawl etc.) go to the Central Admin site and then to your Shared Service Provider. in the SSP Select Seearch Adminstration. in the menu on the left you can find the link "Content sources". In the following page you can select the Content Source (something like "SharePoint sites" (out of the box). selct edit in the context menu and define your crawl schedule. Then select the "start a full crawl" checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that you've indexed your site.

Comment: Colin explains below.  Indexes are created by the crawl.